# Recommended Accessories for a Canon T2i

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon-550d, accessories

This is an awesome site. I've been on here the past few days and am really enjoying reading the questions and suggestions, and have conjured up the bravery to ask a question myself.

I bought a Canon T2i off of a friend last year for a decent amount of money, and I've really enjoyed playing with and using it. My girlfriend is into fashion and has her own blog and stuff, so I take photos for her. I'm also thinking of taking photos for my university's yearbook next year and stuff like that, and so am hoping to pick up a couple of accessories over the summer.

When I bought the camera, I received the T2i body, the standard EF-S 18-55mm lens, three batteries (one legitimate Canon, two knock-offs), and a Canon battery grip and a charger.

I'm wondering what accessories I should look into adding over the summer. I think my biggest priority is adding a lens to my collection, as well as a tripod, and perhaps some other things. As a college student, I am really looking to make this as affordable as possible.

I'm up for suggestions of any sort. I'm by no means a professional, or even very good, but I would like to think of myself as a budding enthusiast who is really looking to hone his photography skills.

Thank you once again. You guys are awesome, keep it up!

Comment: Hiya, welcome to the site! This is a duplicate, I'm afraid, the only difference is a slight model revision in the camera.

Comment: I somehow managed to submit an answer I was writing when it was marked as a duplicate. It is a little personalized to a college student's unique situation.